# Become immortal - blessing or curse?

Tags: meaning-of-life, emotions, human-nature

This question is really important for understand what's actually matter to us as humans. Having a limited life span is factor by which everyone of us is driven to something (goals/dreams/fulfilling responsibilities). What could happen if we didn't have that life span limit ?

Become immortal might be not bad thing after all if our loved ones are also immortal but what if you are only one in this world who is immortal ?

Comment: Similar post [what-are-arguments-against-the-option-of-immortality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55873/what-are-arguments-against-the-option-of-immortality)

Comment: Strangely enough Tolkien has a lot to say about this, particularly in The Silmarillion.
Elves are an immortal species, and their entire character is entirely based upon their immortality. They are a peaceful, isolationist species, and Tolkien explains why at typically Tolkien detail levels.

Comment: This seems to ask for opinions on what "actually matters" and what is "good/bad" about immortality. Since this is inherently subjective it is off-topic here.

Comment: ... *flesh and blood* cannot inherit the kingdom of God...For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality...And as we have borne the image of the earthy, we shall also bear the image of the heavenly...Death is swallowed up in victory.

Comment: i've seen this (question) in a philosophy encyclopedia: it is not "off topic"... however, i can't think it will generate great answers, either!

Comment: in later chinese mahayana the buddha is said to be immortal, more or less. i'm not sure what sort of teaching device this is, but your comments on others may be part of that

Comment: The novels I have read have demonstrate that immortality is mixed in terms of benefits and downsides. The Belgariad is one such novel. Tolkien also states that Elves and mortals envy each other, suggesting that neither side has a better deal. Anne Rice is much more gloomy, but some of the vampires enjoy their semi-immortality, while others such as Louis, do not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are arguments against the option of immortality?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55873/what-are-arguments-against-the-option-of-immortality)

Answer (score 1):

> Become immortal - blessing or curse?

You come into existence and become immortal.  You could extent this idea this way--'You come into existence from something mortal and become immortal'. From a mortal thing you become immortal.  Is it reasonable?

Become immortal....who/what? Body or soul?

If the answer is 'body', it never happens for it is made up of cells.  Since it is emerged, it must decay.  When you stick to these terms only, you get only two choices.  But when you consider these two terms, you are actually confining to a dual state.  There must be/is a thing which is non-dual that transcends both.  When you realize it, you would never feel this as a problem because you do not gain or lose anything new.

> Become immortal might be not bad thing after all if our loved ones are
>   also immortal but what if you are only one in this world who is
>   immortal ?

Fundamentally others are also like you.  So this type of a state has no coherence.  **If you are immortal others are also immortal.** When you realize what immortal is, you will realize who the loved ones are.

---

cf.: Is your deep sleep blessing or curse?

If you are suffering from any ailments or if you are worrying about something, you will say that deep sleep is certainly a blessing. On the contrary, if you giving more importance to happiness than peacefulness and if you are feeling that deep sleep loses your happiness, you will certainly say that it is a curse.  But don't forget that when you deal these two words you are comparing that state  from another state.

What would be you answer if you are comparing waking state from deep sleep? You might say it is a blessing or curse; but only after you woke up (as I mentioned in the above para).  But during that period did you **feel** any kind of happiness of **blessing** or worries of **curse**?  Your answer will certainly be 'No'.  If so, similar is the case of immortality. *TO BECOME IMMORTAL IS BEYOND BLESSING AND CURSE.*

Comment: How is it that others are necessarily immortal as well? Furthermore, it not being biologically possible is not the point here, and the duality sleeping/waking seems to be a far cry from mortal/immortal life. Can you expand on these things?

Comment: "How is it that others are necessarily immortal as well?" ~ I have mentioned it in my answer. Fundamentally every human body is made up of cells or tiny particles. Then what is left? See this: http://www.himavanti.org/en/c/teachings-of-masters/swami-vivekananda-the-nature-of-the-soul-and-its-goal.  "...and the duality sleeping/waking seems to be a far cry from mortal/immortal life." ~ You should focus on the thing that is immortal. If you couldn't, you could use it for understanding the state that is beyond blessing and curse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Biological Immortality

I would just point out (for starters) that biological immortality is not "genuine" immortality (deathlessness). Tolkein's elves are biologically immortal in the sense that they don't physically age. But they can be "slain" (in battle, for example) just like anyone else. That said, I'll take biological immortality if/when I can get it. That might actually be possible within some of our lifespans, as aging is clearly a genetic phenomenon. There is probably a gene for aging that has Darwinian survival value because it enables the evolutionary process itself. I personally also believe in the spiritual type of immortality (without adhering to any particular sect). But know what? I'd choose the biological variety any day of the week....

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how someone could achieve immortality. Just saying immortal makes humans open to much more accumulated risks than a mortal. Specifically, everything irreversible would seem significant.

The obvious potential curse is: In most types of immortality defined by humans, you likely either forget, or never forget, or even unallowed to forget by the law. But humanity as a whole is in effect very near immortal, which selectively forget and relearn things in its process of rebirth. This worked well as far as we know it.

In a world reasonably close to reality, we could only achieve immortality by solving each of the problems, using resources to maintain it, stopping enforcing preserving abilities that backfire, and slowly adapting to the immortal way of living. We would also invent more other technologies useful for immortals. We won't be open to all the risks all of a sudden.

If it's all of a sudden, we could also always have extreme possibilities such as an immortal terrorist stronger than nukes, or permanent torture by a immortal dictator. And you have infinite time to wait for such possibilities.